# How to get first value in groupby , TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have df, like this

```
States Counts
AK     one
AK     two
AK     one
LO     one
LO     three
LO     three
```

trying to get most occured counts for each status

my code:

```
 df.groupby('States')['Counts'].value_counts().first(), gives
```

`TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`

expected output:

```
  States Counts
  AK     one
  LO     three
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `lambda` function:

```
df = df.groupby('States')['Counts'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
  States    val
0     AK    one
1     LO  three
```

Comment: thank you @jezrael, any other shorter way ?

Comment: @pyd - hmmm, I see dupe with `mode`, not sure how working it and maybe `x.mode.iat[0]` is necessary

Comment: `df.groupby('States')['Counts'].apply(lambda x : x.mode())`